# MIMO Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm looking into implementing a Multiple Input Multiple Output neural network. The neural network is to guess the X and Y position given some inputs based on a signal for example:

Given the Signal Strength and Signal Power it will then give out an X and Y coordinate based on training data.

I want to use the tensorflow libraries in python but don't know where to even begin. I looked at their CNN and RNN tutorials but it is not what I am looking for. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I found [this library](https://github.com/andychisholm/mimo) for building MIMO networks with tensorflow.

Comment: Just a point of terminology: nobody really calls this MIMO. When people discuss neural networks, they are MIMO by default. Try looking tensorflow's MNIST example. Based on your example, you definitely don't want a CNN, though an RNN may be interesting if the time dimension provides some information on state (which in location it certainly does unless you can teleport)

Comment: Hi Aandnp, I found a diagram that more or less shows what I want to do. Is there any suggestion you can give me? Here is the picture of the diagram:
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org.uplib.idm.oclc.org/mediastore/IEEE/content/media/6893068/6900900/6900931/6900931-fig-3-large.gif